# ¿Cómo crear login con certificado digital en PHP?

Tags: php, autenticación, certificado-ssl

¿Cómo puedo crear un login web para autenticarse a través de un certificado digital en vez de utilizar usuario y contraseña? Todo sobre lenguaje PHP.

¿Alguien tiene idea o me puede indicar cómo se hace?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Antes de poder responderte debes proporcionarnos todos los datos de tu entorno (sistema operativo, servidor web, interfaz entre servidor y php, etc) ya que el intercambio de certificados se hace en el lado del servidor web y no en el lado de PHP. PHP es un mero receptor de los datos del certificado enviados por el cliente. En apache, por ejemplo, basta con poner en el `.htaccess`, `<Directory>` o `<VirtualHost>` un [`SSLVerifyClient require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient).

Comment: Mientras respondes con los datos de la plataforma exactos, he redactado una respuesta con los parámetros generales de un servidor apache y un script PHP básico.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es acotada ya que la autenticación por certificado digital no requiere de desarrollo de complejos sistemas de formularios HTML, bases de datos, etc. Voto la reapertura de la pregunta.

Comment: No sé quién abrió finalmente la respuesta, muchas gracias a todos :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tu solución de autenticación requiere configurar el servidor web para recibir certificados de cliente y, una vez configurado correctamente, leer en PHP los datos del certificado entregado por el servidor web para almacenar los datos del certificado de cliente deseados.

### Configuración del servidor web

En caso de ser un servidor web apache en una máquina Linux basada en una distribución Debian debes haber completado los siguientes pasos:

- Activar HTTPS (`a2enmod ssl`).
- Permitir opciones en `.htaccess` (`AllowOverride All`).
- Incluir la CA de los certificados de cliente:

  - Puede incluirse el certificado de la CA dentro de la cadena del certificado del servidor (opción `SSLCertificateFile`).
  - Puede indicarse explícitamente con `SSLCACertificateFile`.
- En las páginas protegidas por certificado de cliente se debe incluir `SSLVerifyClient require` en el archivo `.htaccess`.

### Configuración en PHP

Para autenticar a un usuario con su certificado de cliente te recomiendo que crees un directorio llamado `entrada` y dentro de él crees el archivo `.htaccess` con el siguiente contenido:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
```

Posteriormente puedes crear un archivo `index.php` que tenga lo siguiente:

```
<?php
/* Iniciamos el funcionamiento de las sesiones de PHP */
session_start();
/* Guardamos en una variable de sesión los datos del certificado */
$_SESSION['certificado'] = [
  'SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN' => $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN'],
  'SSL_CLIENT_S_DN' => $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN'],
  'SSL_CLIENT_V_END' => $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_V_END'],
];
/* Redirigimos a la página "pagina_secreta.php" fuera de "/entrada" */
header('Location: /pagina_secreta.php');
```

El script `pagina_secreta.php` de la raíz (y cualquier otro script que requiera que el usuario esté autenticado) debería implementar lo siguiente al comienzo:

```
<?php
/* Iniciamos el funcionamiento de las sesiones de PHP */
session_start();
/* Comprobamos si tenemos los datos del certificado */
if (!isset($_SESSION['certificado']) {
  header('Location: /entrada');
  die();
}
/* A partir de aquí tenemos los datos del certificado "garantizados" */
```

### Funcionamiento

- Cuando el usuario desea visitar el recurso que está protegido (en este caso el script `pagina_secreta.php` del directorio raíz del sitio web) éste comprobará la existencia de los datos del certificado en las variables de sesión (`$_SESSION['certificado']`) y si no existen esos datos redirigirá al usuario/navegador al directorio protegido por el certificado de cliente (`/entrada`) que tratará de ejecutar el script `/entrada/index.php`.
- El servidor web se negará a ejecutar el script `/entrada/index.php` mientras el usuario no entregue un certificado de cliente válido al servidor web.
- Cuando `/entrada/index.php` es finalmente ejecutado haciendo uso de un certificado de cliente válido, éste guardará los datos necesarios en la variable de sesión `$_SESSION['certificado']` para que sean usados cuando se requieran y redirigimos de nuevo al usuario al recurso protegido.
- Una vez de vuelta en el recurso protegido, `pagina_secreta.php`, se comprobará que la variable de sesión ya existe y, por lo tanto, se permitirá la ejecución del resto del script.